# Index for identity in SQL Server automatic or not

Tags: sql-server

I have a huge table for logging. The definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TRACELOG]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TYPE] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [DATEHEURE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PROGRAMME] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [APPLICATION] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [text] NULL,
    [UTILISATEUR] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Indexes are like this:

[image]

The table has now about 18 millions or row. When I run a query using `ID = 123456`, the query is very long.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TRACELOG 
WHERE ID = 123456
```

I'm very surprised... My question is: in a table with `IDENTITY`, is there an implicit index created on the column in question (not visible in indexes?) or have I to create manually?

Comment: All the indexes are listed in your image. Unless you create an index it doesn't exist.

Comment: *"is there an implicit index created on the column"* Nope. There are very few things that implicitly have an index created on them. A Primary Key and Unique Constraint are the main candidates.

Comment: **NO**- the `IDENTITY` does **NOT** automatically create an index - not at all. What **does create** an automatic (and by default clustered) index is the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint. But not every `IDENTITY` column is a primary key - you have to **specify that** if you want it that way

Comment: Separate note, why are you using the `text` data type? That was deprecated in **2005** (*16 years ago*). It is *long* past time you stopped using the data type.

Comment: Your table has no primary key. That's bad. Setting the primary key is far more important than worrying about indexes. A unique index is no substitute for a primary key

Comment: If your table is a log rather than a relational structure, why an identity column at all? I would just create a clustered index on the datetime and additional non-clustered indexes to support your query use cases.

Comment: Thanks for all your very useful comments. I'm not the creator of this table. @marc_s : can you make a reply so i can approve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO** - having an `IDENTITY` column does not automatically create an index.

What does create an automatic (and by default clustered) index is the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint - which is often used on `IDENTITY` columns.

But not every `IDENTITY` column has to be the primary key of its table - you have to specify that if you want it that way.

Comment: Index is also automatically created for unique constraint.